# HTML Horizontal draggable DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, drag

Im pretty new to html/css and currently trying to make an horizontal draggable slider for an Smartphone-Webapp.

Basically want i am searching for are three divs in a horizontal line, where div 1 and 3 are out of view.
If im dragging div 2 to left or right, 1 or 3 should appear.

Im creating my app with react and got already the div 2 to be draggable via an library.

Comment: Can you share with us what have you tried? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I dont know if this would be any helpful. I tried a lot and nothing worked like i descripted. Of course i could share my current component if that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make a `parent div` and add three `div`s to it. Stack the `div`s next to each other and for `parent div` add `overflow-x: scroll`. Each child should have a width and height to that of the screen. For that add `min-width: 100vw; and min-height: 100vh;`.

Now, to display the central `div`, the scrollbar of the `div` has to be moved.

`parent.scrollLeft += document.querySelector(".C1").clientWidth;`
This will position the scrollbar to the center. Essentially, it will move the scroll bar by the width of the screen.

Scroll down when you run the snippet to see the horizontal scrollbar.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("Parent");
parent.scrollLeft += document.querySelector(".C1").clientWidth;
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#Parent {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: flex;   
}

.C1, .C2, .C3 {
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.C1 {
    background-color: red;    
}

.C2 {
    background-color: green;    
}

.C3 {
    background-color: blue;    
}
```

```html
<div id="Parent">
    <div class="C1">
    </div>
    <div class="C2">
    </div>
    <div class="C3">
    </div>
</div>
```